# How can I bind a RadioButton in a ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, controltemplate

I am using a ListBox with controlTemplate to show a RadioButton with the ListBoxItem.
Here i want to set the IsChecked Property of RadioButton to true and does the necessary wpf Binding for this. below is the xaml

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" DisplayMemberPath="ProductName" Grid.Column="0" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,2,0,30" AlternationCount="2">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">                                       
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsRadioButtonChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                        </RadioButton>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
                <!--Alternate Style Indexing-->
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

Code behind class for this is

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ListStylesViewModel();
    }
}
```

ListStyleViewModel class is

```
public class ListStylesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string prodName;
    private List<Products> products;
    private bool isChecked = true;

    public ListStylesViewModel()
    {
        ListStyleModel model = new ListStyleModel();
        this.Products = model.GetProducts();
    }

    public string ProductName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.prodName;
        }
        set
        {
            this.prodName = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("ProductName");
        }
    }

    public List<Products> Products
    {
        get
        {
            return this.products;
        }
        set
        {
            this.products = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Products");
        }
    }

    public bool IsRadioButtonChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isChecked;
        }
        set
        {
            this.isChecked = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }

    #region
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string pptName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pptName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

please advise what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: I think the main problem is, that your `IsRadioButtonChecked` is implemented inside `ListStylesViewModel` while it should be implemented inside `Products`, so the checked state is tracked for each item instead of once for the whole listbox.

Comment: i want the RadioButton to be implemented in ListStyleViewModel only,  got the answer now.(need to set DataContext on this control)

Answer (score 0):

The binding expression

```
IsChecked="{Binding IsRadioButtonChecked,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

in the ControlTemplate uses the ListBoxItem as source object. However, ListBoxItem does not have a `IsRadioButtonChecked` property.

Since the binding source property is in the ListStylesViewModel instance in the `DataContext` of the ListBox, your binding expression should look like this:

```
IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.IsRadioButtonChecked,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
```